# How do I return a value from a jQuery deferred chain?

Tags: jquery, deferred

Given this example, I was hoping that `hello world` would be bubbled up the chain. Certain Deferred/Promise frameworks can though, but it seems like jQuery can't do this.

```js
function function1() {
  return function2().done(function(pelle) {
    return "hello world";
  });
}

function function2() {
  return $.Deferred().resolve("function2");
}

function1().done(function(response) {
  console.log("response", response);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ysbjr1nm/

How can I refactor this code to achieve this?

Comment: Do you expect to see **hello world** instead of **response function2**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using wrong callback method in `function1`. You want `then` not `done`

Promise chains  work by return in then returning to next `then` in the chain

```
function function1() {
  return function2().then(function(pelle) {
    return "hello world";
  });
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ysbjr1nm/2/)**</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

So to illustrate the problem stated in question objective is to project the promise returned for subsequent usage.

You need to use **then()** method which allows you to "project" a promise.Before 1.8 you could use **pipe()** method also.As use of `pipe()` has been depreciated from 1.8 onwards (reference https://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) use `then()`as suggested by @charlietfl.

So now if you change your code like this

```
function function1() {
  return function2().then(function(pelle) {
    return "hello world";
  });
}

function function2() {
  return $.Deferred().resolve("function2");
}

function1().done(function(response) {
  console.log("response", response);
});
```

It would result in "**response hello world**".

You can read the thorough discussion on the same http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ysbjr1nm/3/).

Comment: pipe has been deprecated for a long time

Comment: @charlietfl thanks yes you are right.Here is the official documentation from 1.8 it has been advised to use then.https://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/.Although I saw in fiddle pipe still works.Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: no point placing edit in answer when the whole answer is using a deprecated method...just update whole answer with proper way and get rid of all mention of pipe

Comment: Moreover, editing affords your critics the opportunity to re-upvote your answer.